# Issue with CKeditor

Tags: wysiwyg, 9

I am building in Drupal 9.0.5 and just discovered that the Styles dropdown menu in the CKEditor is disabled even though I have classes listed. Not sure what's wrong. I've read and read and I'm pretty sure I've set it up correctly. I tried setting a new text format, and it won't even let me add CKEditor as an option. When I select it, it does nothing. It's supposed to give me options for the toolbar. I've used this in D7 and D8, so I wouldn't think this would be an issue, but...Please see the screenshots attached. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Classes added to full html text format:
[![Classes added to full html text format][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyXsh.jpg

Trying to add a class in a content type text editor, but it's disabled:
[![Trying to add a class in a content type text editor, but it's disabled:][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW4O1.jpg

Tried creating a new text format "HTML with styles", but it won't let me access CKEditor:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXUIP.jpg

Comment: Styles will only appear in the styles dropdown when the appropriate tag is currently selected. For example, if you have a style that applies to links (`<a>`), the dropdown will only show the style of there's a link in the content and you have the link text highlighted or your cursor is within the link text. You can see the active element in the bottom of the editor.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. Such simple answer. I like simple.